# Facebook share count from debugger page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-share

How can I get number of shares that is shown on [facebook debugger page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) via API?

I've empirically found it to fit the most for comparing with share counters from some others social networks, but it looks like this number does not show up anywhere except that debugger page.

Here are some details.

By now I've found 3 API calls that return somewhat relevant data:

- via graph API: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Farzamas.academy%2Fspecial%2Fruslit
- via FQL: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http%3A%2F%2Farzamas.academy%2Fspecial%2Fruslit%27
- via some old API: https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http%3A%2F%2Farzamas.academy%2Fspecial%2Fruslit&format=json

The values in second and third call are identical, for my test url http://arzamas.academy/special/ruslit the current ones are

```
share_count: 492, like_count: 5042, comment_count: 491, total_count: 6025
```

The counter from the first call is named `shares` and is equal to `total_count` from second and third call.

When you paste the url in [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and click 'Show existing scrape information', one of the first rows in table is

`Canonical URL: http://arzamas.academy/special/ruslit (6025 likes, 1635 shares)`

Number of likes is equal to `total_count` from API calls, but how can I get that 1635 shares number via API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that specifying Graph API version newer than 2.0 gives another number (`share.share_count`), for some reason it is the sum of both numbers, that are shown in debugger (likes + shares). 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%3Fid%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Farzamas.academy%252Fspecial%252Fruslit&version=v2.3&

So now I can get counters from two calls and subtract to get the value that I need. There are obvious cons for this method:

- 2 calls
- token requirement
- looks not very reliable

But it should work, I'll try to implement it and will mark this answer as correct if there are no additional caveats and until there is no better solution.